# Fundamental Question on Bitcoin: How would one convert his "bananas" into bitcoins?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, currencies

In one of the presentations by Andreas Antonopoulos on Bitcoin, he said that "there are 6 billion people in this world who have no banking facilities, who live in places where they have cash or barter based societies. In these places, where banking services will never reach and the nearest bank is 100 miles upstream, where the only form of technology is a Nokia 1000 feature phone, every phone become a banking service"

My question is this. In a scenario as described above, how would one transact his/her hard money or the farm products (say bananas) using a basic phone without any banking facility? In other words, how will one convert his "bananas" to bitcoins?

Comment: What actually banking service provides to you in your context?

Answer (score 1):

> how would one transact his/her hard money or the farm
>   products (say bananas)

It is **not possible** to transact/transfer/convert bananas to anything else. The same situation is with any other things in real and online world.

So, if you have bananas you have only one possibility: **exchange** them for something to a neighbour. Give me your bananas and I will give you my old shoes. If we are far away to each other, we should construct a chain of exchanges: you sell your bananas to somebody (exchange for your local money), he delivers bananas and sell them to me (exchange for my local money).

> using a basic phone without any banking facility?

We do not need phone and banking at all here. But if you want to use a phone in this chain of exchanges, you may have it in your pocket.